# C+Python and core dumps

Tags: python, c, gdb, swig

I use Python with C (with SWIG), where the main module in Python processes data using C library. It crashes somewhere in the C library, so I want to analyse core dump and find the bug.

But, I do not have *a regular executable* to run with gdb, I have `main.py`, the library `_library.so` generated from my C code, and `.o` object files from C. How should  feed gdb to see the core dump with this mixed code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC you can do this by running python through gdb, i.e.

```
gdb python
gdb> run -m main.py
```